# RTL8188CUS Wireless dongle perpetually connecting but never connected

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.04 with no Internet access, my WiFi dongle has been assigned an rtl8171 module although it is apparently using a generic driver.

I can enter my WiFi password, but then it just shows the connecting animation forever.

Once it told me that it had connected to the home network, but that didn't seem to mean much - it continued connecting, and still no Internet access.

I'd like to know how to ensure it is using a valid driver.

Output from `lsusb && usb-devices` follows.

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:0a19 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c019 Logitech, Inc. Optical Tilt Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=05 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8176 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu


T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=03 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8187 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Manufacturer_Realtek_RTL8187_
S:  Product=RTL8187_Wireless
S:  SerialNumber=0015AF6522B4
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=rtl8187
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb && usb-devices` terminal command.

Comment: And rtl8171 is a wired Ethernet driver. it is unrelated.

Comment: It's coming, I just need to transfer it to a computer with Internet (can't access my phone)

Comment: Done - sorry for the delay and formatting, I got it going through my phone, but not the code style blocks.

Comment: It looks like you have two USB adapters connected. Is it the case?

Comment: No - just one, my other usb devices are phone, mouse, speakers and hard drive. I have on board wifi, but it's very weak.

Comment: And what is `0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter`?

Comment: That must be your built-in adapter connected through usb. It is old 201.11g. You better disable it, not to confuse things.

Comment: I wrote an answer with two solutions. Online and offline. In your case offline with manual download of the driver is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two Realtek adapters connected to USB.

Regarding `0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter` you can install a better driver. Run in terminal

```
   sudo apt-get install git build-essential
   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git
   cd rtl8192cu
   make
   sudo make install
```

It should solve the issue.

You will have to re-install this driver after each kernel upgrade.

**I pushed DKMS module of this driver to my ppa.** If you install it from there, you will not need to re-install it.

It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipospilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

**Important!!!** If you previously installed this driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git, you will need to run

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8192cu.conf
```

to get it work. Previous install blacklists rtl8192cu.

And if you installed rtlwifi-new-dkms, you should remove it too.

I will later remove rtl8192cu from rtlwifi-dkms, because it does not work well.

Comment: Now when I connect to the WiFi, the whole computer freezes indefinitely, I tried restarting three or four times with the same result.

Comment: OK. I know how to fix it. First run `sudo apt-get remove rtlwifi-new-dkms && sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`

Comment: And then install another driver from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. You can try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

http://distrustsimplicity.net/articles/nvidia-jetson-tk1-wifi/