# Wifi randomly disconnects in 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

My computer's wifi keeps disconnecting every few minutes. I have to reconnect whenever that happens. What could be the cause of this? My wifi adapter is an Edimax EW-7811Un. (EDIT: This is a USB adapter)

When I run `ifconfig`:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:64:bf:38:6c
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:21 Memory:f7ae0000-f7b00000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:208 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:16907 (16.9 KB)  TX bytes:16907 (16.9 KB)

wlx74da3868582f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:68:58:2f
          inet addr:192.168.1.205  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4162:6f23:ab3e:c821/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:91 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:12747 (12.7 KB)  TX bytes:16395 (16.3 KB)
```

EDIT: Running `lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Is it a USB adapter?

Comment: Yes, it's a USB adapter. I should edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Most of the times it is your router shutting down for some reason. Check your router logs to begin with and check for errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTL8188CUS Wireless dongle perpetually connecting but never connected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632270/rtl8188cus-wireless-dongle-perpetually-connecting-but-never-connected)